# Как перевести введенное с клавиатуры число 7.0(разделитель точка) в double?

Tags: java, конвертация

Как перевести введенное с клавиатуры число в double у которого разделитель точка?
Если использовать nextDouble() то нужно вводить число с разделителем запятая (7,0), а как перевести число 7.0 например?
Предварительно нужно проверить введено ли число, а не буква какая нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить число "7.0" в виде строки и преобразовать в double таким образом:

```
String text = "7.0"; // значение бери откуда тебе надо
double value = Double.parseDouble(text);
```

Про проверку строки на число можешь посмотреть тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543729/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-parseable-to-a-double

Answer (score 1):

Используйте класс Double

```
Double f = new Double("7.0");
double num = f.doubleValue();
```

если параметром будет не число, то в результате NumberFormatException

Answer (score 1):

Надо озаботиться `NumberFormat` который понимает разделитель `.`, например:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
Number number = format.parse("7.0"); //если будет не число выкинет эксепшн
double d = number.doubleValue();
```